# 100 prisoner and a light bulb probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve the problem of 100 prisoners and light bulb using generating functions.

The problem is a random prisoner out of 100 is sent a room with a light bulb in it each hour. How can you guarantee that all prisoners have been in the room at least once and what is the expected number of turns for this?

Solution is prisoners choose 1 person among themselves calling him counter. If a prisoner enters the room he turns the light on if it is off and leaves it if it is on but each prisoner turns the light on only one time ie if a prisoner turned the light on once he will not do so again. When counter enters he turns the light off if it is on and leaves it if it is off. This way if counter turns the light off 99 times they guarantee that everyone has been in the room.

Now if x^k denotes the probability that this process ends in k turns i can use the generating function of x^k's to find the expected value. However i have no idea how i can find the probability.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  Suppose the light is initially off, and prisoner $100$ is the counter.  Prisoner $1$ enters and turns the light on. Then prisoners $2$ through $99$ enter and leave the light on.  Now prisoner $100$ enters and turns the light off.  Now no one will ever turn the light on again.  I suspect you have copied the problem statement incorrectly.

Comment: The minimum number of turns has to be 198 turns as each 99 prisoner must be in the room at least once and after each prisoner the counter must be in the room. Finding probability for 198 is easier but it gets too complicated even at 199 and 200 turns

Comment: Im sorry it should be a prisoner will turn the light only once not when it enters the room for the first time.

Comment: Do you want any answer, or do you want an answer with generating functions? Because I think I can compute that expected value directly.

Comment: I already found an answer on the internet but i want to compute using generating functions if it is possible of course.

Comment: You might find [this writeup](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~wwu/papers/100prisonersLightBulb.pdf) interesting. It is an extended discussion of the $100$ prisoners and $1$ light bulb problem, including a derivation of the expectation of the single counter protocol's expected runtime. It also discusses its various, and several other faster solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Generating functions don't look like the right way to go to me, because as you say, it will be difficult to calculate the probability that the process takes a particular number of turns.  Instead, I suggest you attack it like the coupon collector's problem.  Suppose $k$ prisoners, other than the counter have entered the room.  We need the counter to enter the room and turn of the light and then we need some prisoner who has not yet entered to enter the room.

The probability that the counter is chosen to enter the room is ${1\over100}.$  Since we have a geometric distribution the expected number of turns until he enters the room is $100$.  Then we need a new prisoner to enter.  There are $99-k$ new prisoners, so the expected number of turns until one of them enters is ${100\over99-k}.$

I'm certain you'll be able to work it out now.  One note of caution though: the answer depends on whether the light is initially on or off.

Comment: Yeah this solution seems much easier and i might just give up on generating functions.

Comment: Though the strategy can be adapted ver easily so that initial condition doesn't matter.

Comment: @O.Bilge The strategy can be adapted easily, but the expectation depends on whether the light bulb is initially on or off.  If it's initially on, we can't really get started until the counter comes in and turns it off.  If it's initially off, we just need any non-counter to be chosen.

Comment: Well considering the prisoners are aware of the turn they're in, for the first turn only if counter enters he turns the light off without counting and if another person enters he leaves the light on with the condition that he will never turn it on again, I think expected value will not be affected by the initial condition of light. Am I wrong? By adapting strategy I meant this.